# Using alt in terminal emulator

Tags: terminal, hotkeys, gnome-terminal

I have many key combinations involving <kbd>Alt</kbd> in Emacs. When I run it in gnome-terminal and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, it invokes menu items like "File" or "Edit", instead of executing Emacs commands.

How can I change this behavior? Or should I go for another terminal emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may depend on the version of `gnome-terminal`, but on Debian squeeze you can configure this under Edit > Keyboard shortcuts..., uncheck the first checkbox in the dialog ("Enable menu access keys").